# Получение видео через бота telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

есть телеграм бот, надо получить отправленное ему видео в любом формате (в байтах или ссылку)

Answer (score 1):

Для тех кому интересно ответ был методом getFile (по питоновски bot.get_file(message.video.file_id))
из этого метода я извлёк file_path тк это словарь (прошу прощения это не обычный словарь, но выглядит как он (извлечь из него file_path можно так sa.file_path где sa

> bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)

)) дальше я нашёл в апи телеги вот такую сслыку

> `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`

где `<token>` это токен 
а `<file_path>` это тот самый file_path и при заходе на это ссылку, воуля вы скачали видосик с телеги